# Error when typing error number

Tags: java

Someone can explain my problem? When i try inputting comma number, i always get

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.2"

my code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     // TODO add your handling code here:
    String showInputDialog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Line: ");
    int liningg = Integer.parseInt(showInputDialog);
    double volume = liningg*liningg*liningg;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Last result are: "+volume );

}
```

Comment: 1.2 is not an integer value.

Comment: Use double.parseDouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NumberFormatException For input string: "1.2"

"1.2" is not an integer, so it can't be parsed as an integer value.

Maybe you want:

```
double liningg = Double.parseDouble(showInputDialog);
```